# Special Family of metrics on transitive lie algebroids.

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\rho:E\longrightarrow TM$ is a transitive Lie Algebroid, then $L=ker\rho$ is bundle of lie algebras. Suppose $\Gamma:TM\longrightarrow E$ be a linear splitting. Define 
$$\nabla_X s=[\Gamma(X),s]$$
$\nabla$ is linear connection on $L$..

I'm trying to find  semi-Reimannian metrics on $L$ like $g$ which are compatible to $\nabla$ $\big(Xg(s_1,s_2)=<\nabla_X s_1 , s_2>+<s_1,\nabla_X s_2>\big)$and the below condition satisfies:

for all $p\in M$, $$g_p([x,y],z)+g_p(y,[x,z])=0$$ where $x,y,z\in L_p$ are arbitrary.

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understood it correctly: you have a vector bundle $L$ such that each fibre is a Lie algebra (actually a lie algebra bundle) and you want a metric (with funny signature) on $L$ which is a kind of skewsymmetric version of the Killing form at each fibre, is it?

If you were looking for a inner product satisfying $\langle [x,y],z\rangle -\langle x,[y,z]\rangle=0$, then the Killing form would do... otherwise (and this seems to be the case), my suggestion is to play around with the signature of you metric to see if you can achieve this "skewsymmetric Killing form".

Comment: The original poster asked the following: "any suggestion?"
I provided one, that is based on my understanding of their problem.

Actually, before Jyrki Lahtonen's edition I had the following sentence before my answer:

"I am sorry, I do not have enough reputation to leave a comment, and this is a comment, not an answer."